# How would I make this block of code cleaner?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

So I"m currently in the middle of programming a warn system for my bot, and overall the following code is working properly as it should, I'm just unsatisfied of its structure or how it was made.

```js
} else if (!reason && userToWarn) {
           if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS") &&  !membertoWarn.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
               membertoWarn.createDM()
               .then(dm => {
                    if (!warns[userToWarn.id]) {
                        warns[userToWarn.id] = {
                            warns: 0
                        }

                        warns[userToWarn.id].warns++;

                        fs.writeFile("./warnings.json", JSON.stringify(warns), (err) => {
                            if (err) console.log(err);
                        })
                    } else if (warns[userToWarn.id]) {
                        warns[userToWarn.id].warns++;
                        if (warns[userToWarn.id].warns > 4) {
                            membertoWarn.kick("Too much warnings.");
                            return message.channel.send(userToWarn.username + " was kicked, they had too many warnings.");
                        }
                        fs.writeFile("./warnings.json", JSON.stringify(warns), (err) => {
                            if (err) {
                                console.log(err);
                            }
                        })
                    }
                    dm.send("You have been warned in **" + membertoWarn.guild.name + "** because of: no specified reason");
                    message.channel.send(`${userToWarn.tag} was warned. No reason provided.`);
               })
               .catch(console.error);
           } else if (membertoWarn.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
               message.reply("You cannot warn a moderator!");
           }
       }
```

So does anyone have any idea on how I could make this cleaner, or shorter perhaps?

Comment: There exists a https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ that might be a better fit for this type of questions

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on the codereview stack.

Comment: @dennlinger [Don't use the existence of Code Review as a reason to close a question](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/287400). From now on evaluate the question and use a reason like; needs focus, primarily opinion-based, etc.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer, but I still believe this is also wrongly placed on SO. Therefore, I will keep my close vote up, despite for potentially different reasoning (attracting opinionated answers).

Answer (score 0):

You could definitely simplify some of the code by eliminating the if statement, this will remove a lot of duplication.

> if (!warns[userToWarn.id])

Like so:

```
} else if (!reason && userToWarn) {
    if (message.member.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS") &&  !membertoWarn.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
        membertoWarn.createDM()
        .then(dm => {
            warns[userToWarn.id] = warns[userToWarn.id] || { warns: 0 };
            warns[userToWarn.id].warns++;
            if (warns[userToWarn.id].warns > 4) {
                membertoWarn.kick("Too much warnings.");
                return message.channel.send(userToWarn.username + " was kicked, they had too many warnings.");
            }
            fs.writeFile("./warnings.json", JSON.stringify(warns), (err) => {
                if (err) console.log(err);
            })
            dm.send("You have been warned in **" + membertoWarn.guild.name + "** because of: no specified reason");
            message.channel.send(`${userToWarn.tag} was warned. No reason provided.`);
        })
        .catch(console.error);
    } else if (membertoWarn.hasPermission("KICK_MEMBERS")) {
        message.reply("You cannot warn a moderator!");
    }
}
```